# file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed

Tags: php, linux, vkontakte-api, curl, ssl

Помогите уже всю голову сломал ничего не понимаю.

Вечера тестировал всё работало, пошел спать. Сегодня прихожу и вот тебе здрасте:

Делаю такой запрос:

```
$get_ulpa = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://{$server}?act=a_check&mode=128&key={$key}&ts={$ts}&wait=25&version=3"));
```

Выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /var/www/**** on line 22
```

Пробую так:

```
$get_ulpa = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://{$server}?act=a_check&mode=128&key={$key}&ts={$ts}&wait=25&version=3", false, stream_context_create(["ssl" => ["verify_peer" => false, "verify_peer_name" => false]])));
```

Тогда он мне:

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in
```

Повторю, вчера ещё через этот всё работало:

```
$get_ulpa = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://{$server}?act=a_check&mode=128&key={$key}&ts={$ts}&wait=25&version=3"));
```

Пробовал через Curl, возвращает FALSE:

```
$get_ulpa_curl = curl_init("https://{$server}");
curl_setopt($get_ulpa_curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($get_ulpa_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($get_ulpa_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "act=a_check&mode=128&key={$key}&ts={$ts}&wait=25&version=3");
```

Это если что работа с VK API.

Вообщем рассказываю причину:

Оказалось если сделать этот запрос в адресную строку:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getLongPollServer?need_pts=0&access_token=ТОКЕН&lp_version=3&v=5.92
```

Будет примерно такой ответ:

```
{"response":{"key":"ТУТ БУДЕТ КЛЮЧ","server":"imv4.vk.com\/im3312","ts":1704521391}}
```

Прошу обратить внимание на это:

```
imv4.vk.com\/im3312
```

Так как это JSON строка её нужно декодировать. А я дибил, копипастил с адресной строки с этими / слешами) Вчера то я через декодер работал)

Comment: Может кто-то установил прослушку трафика и подменяет сертификат?

Comment: @Zergatul а может быть такое что вк заблочил? :D